# Formula for homeomorphism between open annulus and punctured open disk

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be an open annulus. That is, let $0<r_1<r_2$ and let $A = \{p: r_1 < d(O,p) < r_2 \}$, where $O$ is the origin.

Let $P$ be the punctured open unit disk. That is, let $P = \{ p: d(O,p) \leq 1 \}\setminus\{O\}$.

I need help finding an explicit homeomorphism from $A$ to $P$, and its inverse.

Comment: That disk isn't open

Answer (score 3):

Yes. But this sounds like homework, so I'll just give a hint: think in polar coordinates, and think *simple*.

Comment: I found it here http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/annulus, but I can't prove it

Comment: All right. Let's forget about homeomorphisms for a moment. Can you come up with a *function* that collapses an annulus down to a punctured disk? Assume that the annulus has inner radius $1$ and outer radius $2$.

Comment: a point in annulus is $(p\cos \theta,p\sin \theta)$ with $1<p<2$, so what is function?

Comment: Forget the sines and cosines. Just write a function $f(r,\theta) = (\mbox{some radius},\mbox{some angle})$.

Comment: I don't know, please help me

Comment: OK.... Let's try a different problem. Let $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb R$ with $a<b$ and $c < d$. Find a homeomorphism from $[a,b]$ to $[c,d]$.

Comment: ok, $f(r,\theta)=(r-1,\theta)$. Right?

Comment: Sounds like a great thing to try. The next step is to prove it's continuous.

Comment: but in this page, it said annulus is homeomorphic to disk with a point removed, not open disk with a point removed

Comment: I would say they erred.

Comment: so What is the one-point compactification of the Euclidean annulus?. I think that is open disk

Comment: The one-point compactification of an open annulus is ... a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bialy, I guess. Certainly it is not an open disk, because an open disk is not compact.

Comment: Wow; On the behalf of everyone I want to thank you for patience and guidance. You might have just posted your question and gone, but you stayed and patiently guided OP toward the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each point in the open annulus has a unique representation as $x+O$ for some $x\in\Bbb R^2$ such that $r_1<||x||<r_2$. Then
 $$h(x+O)=\frac{(||x||-r_1)}{(r_2-r_1)||x||}x+O$$
 is in the punctured open disk of radius $1$ around $O$. Can you see why it is continuos?

Now try to find an inverse. Each point in $B_1(O)\setminus\{O\}$ has a unique representation as $y+O$ with $0<||y||<1$. I've hidden it in the shaded box, if you want to see, hover over it with your mouse.

> $$h^{-1}(y+O)=\frac{||y||(r_2-r_1)+r_1}{||y||}y+O$$