# Difference between: explicit homeomorphism between two topological spaces and showing that two spaces are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology

I tried to find a homeomorphism for the following 4 cases:

1. Boundary of a Unit Square to the Boundary of a Unit Circle, i.e.
   $(Y = ||y||_{\infty} = 1) \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to ( X = ||x||_{2} = 1 ) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$; $y \in Y, x \in X$ are tuples.
2. Interior of a Unit Square to the Interior of a Unit Circle (so both are open), i.e.
   $(Y = ||y||_{\infty} < 1) \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to ( X = ||x||_{2} < 1 ) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$; $y \in Y, x \in X$ are tuples.
3. Punctured Interior of a Unit Square to the Punctured Interior of a Unit Disc (open, with $\{0,0\}$ removed), i.e.
   $(Y = ||y||_{\infty} < 1) \subset \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0,0\} \to ( X = ||x||_{2} < 1 ) \subset \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0,0\}$; $y \in Y, x \in X$ are tuples.
4. Open Annulus of finite radii to Punctured Interior of a Unit Disc (open, with $\{0,0\}$ removed), i.e.
   $(Y = r_1 < ||y||_{2} < r_2) \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to ( X = ||x||_{2} < 1 ) \subset \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0,0\}$ ;$y \in Y, x \in X$ are tuples.

My solutions are as follows (Please correct me if they're incorrect):

1. $f : Y \to X = y . \dfrac{||y||_{\infty}} {||y||_{2}}$;$f^{-1}: X \to Y = x. \dfrac{||x||_{2}} {||x||_{\infty}}$. Verified that a value on the boundary of a square is squashed to lie on the boundary of a circle. Inspired by [Homeomorphism between the unit disc and the unit square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079355/homeomorphism-between-the-unit-disc-and-the-unit-square).
2. \begin{eqnarray}
   f : Y \to X = 
   \begin{cases}
   \{0,0\} \text{ if y = \{0,0\}} \\
   y . \dfrac{||y||_{\infty}} {||y||_{2}} \text{ otherwise}
   \end{cases}
   \end{eqnarray}
   Similarly,
   \begin{eqnarray}
   f^{-1}: X \to Y = 
   \begin{cases}
   \{0,0\} \text{ if x = \{0,0\}} \\
   x. \dfrac{||x||_{2}} {||x||_{\infty}} \text{ otherwise}
   \end{cases}
   \end{eqnarray}
3. $f : Y \to X = y . \dfrac{||y||_{\infty}} {||y||_{2}}$;$f^{-1}: X \to Y = x. \dfrac{||x||_{2}} {||x||_{\infty}}$. Verified that any point in punctured unit square gets squashed to some point within the punctured, open, unit disc. Limits have also been verified.
4. $f : Y \to X = y.\dfrac{||y||_{\infty}-r_1}{||y||_{\infty}(r_2-r_1)}$ ; $f : X \to Y = x.\dfrac{||x||_{\infty}(r_2-r_1)+r_1}{||x||_{\infty}}$. Verified that again, it functions as required. Corrected my solution based on [Formula for homeomorphism between open annulus and punctured open disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425078/formula-for-homeomorphism-between-open-annulus-and-punctured-open-disk).

My questions:
Do we always have to find an explicit homeomorphism between topological spaces to show that they are homeomorphic? I understand that we can use a composition of homeomorphisms, but doesn't that still mean that we're ding an explicit homeomorphism, using several steps instead of one?

- Note: I am learning on my own and am using John.M.Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds.

Thank you.

Comment: I didn’t look at the rest, but the range of your second map is not $X$: for $0\le x<1$ it maps $\langle x,0\rangle$ to $\left\langle\frac{x}{1+x},0\right\rangle$, and $0\le\frac{x}{1+x}<\frac12$ for $0\le x<1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I updated my post with the intended notation, i.e $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ are tuples, in this case 2-tuples. From what I understand of your comment, it looks like $x$ is not a tuple there. With this new notation, could you clarify your comment, please? :)

Comment: I understood your notation. My $\langle x,0\rangle$ is a specific instance of your $x$, i.e., a specific point of $X$. If it really bothers you, replace every $x$ in my comment with $\xi$, and think of $\langle\xi,0\rangle$ as one of your points $x\in X$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, I agree with what you're pointing out and that is exactly my question. Why is it still accepted as a homeomorphism? I use the word accepted because, as mentioned in case 2, it is mentioned as a general homeomorphism for an n-dimensional cube to an n-dimensional ball in Introduction to Topological Manifolds, by John M.Lee (page 28, example 2.25). I have also come across this homeomorphism as a general shrinking mechanism, otherwise. So, why is it accepted?

Comment: It looks to me as if it simply shrinks the unit ball without changing its shape. It is a homeomorphism, but not one between the two different unit balls. I don’t have Lee, but I suspect that you’re misconstruing something there.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott- You are right; that homeomorphism is mentioned as a map between $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{B}^n$. I mistakenly interpreted it as a hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I will edit my solutions where necessary and come back with questions again. Thank you! :)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott- Does my map for the second case make sense now? That map makes a lot of sense for case 3, but in case 2, I cannot justify separating the $\{0,0\}$. Could you please advise?

Comment: You definitely have to make the origin a separate case, and yes, it has to go to itself. You just have to check that the resulting map is still continuous at the origin, and it is.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott- Thank you professor. Continuity was exactly where I needed the clarity on. It is continuous because, when $f$ is restricted to the origin, it's preimage is still open (in the origin), right?

Comment: That’s one way to do it. Alternatively, you can show that if a sequence converges to the origin in $Y$, it’s image converges to the origin in $X$.

Comment: Oh yes, I see; thank you professor. Now, back to the original question: (assuming the solution for case 4 is also correct), what does it mean for two spaces to simply be homeomorphic vs. being able to find an explicit expression? The first comment here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103660/homeomorphism-from-square-to-unit-circle/103669#103669 talks about spaces being homeomorphic, but not being able to write a closed-form expression. Is it because in those cases, one can only find local homeomorphisms between the two spaces?

Comment: Judging by his example, Ben Crowell is thinking of situations in which it’s easy to give a qualitative verbal description of a homeomorphism but extremely difficult to turn that into an explicit expression. There are also general results. For instance, it can be shown that every open [starlike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain) region in $\Bbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. We can describe how a homeomorphism can be constructed, but since we’re talking about all open starlike regions, we can’t give an explicit expression.

Comment: Ok, that example puts things into perspective. Thank you professor!

Comment: You’re welcome!